# SettingsFlyout for UWP (Windows 10)

Tags: uwp, windows-10, flyout

I am currently developing a UWP(windows 10) application, and I am stuck with developing a setting panel for my application.

I understand that there is no more SettingsFlyout like this for UWP windows 10

[image: Settings flyout]

However, I really like the look and feel of it. Hence, is there any ways I could develop a settingsflyout of uwp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SplitView` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/split-view) and set its `DisplayMode` property to `Overlay` and the `PanePlacement` property to `Right`.

```
<SplitView x:Name="SV_SettingsMenu"
           DisplayMode="Overlay"
           PanePlacement="Right"
           >
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Button 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button 2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button 3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>

    <StackPanel Padding="10">
        <Button Click="ToggleSettings">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
        </Button>

        <TextBlock Text="Content"/>
    </StackPanel>
</SplitView>


private void ToggleSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SV_SettingsMenu.IsPaneOpen = !SV_SettingsMenu.IsPaneOpen;
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the wonderful suggestion! However, by any chance, do you know if it is possible to add a header/title in a splitview? Just like the settingsflyout?

Comment: You can add any XAML element to the `Pane` property, in the example it's `StackPanel` and in that you can create a header.

Answer (score 1):

I am not giving you the complete code, but I hope this gives you the right direction:

1. Design a Grid layout similar to the Settings flyout.
2. Use `PaneThemeTransition` to get the animation right
3. Add/Remove the Grid programmatically.